# Creating an MS Access query based on system, status, and date

Tags: ms-access, forms, report

I am just learning Access and have been tasked with creating a database for system access.  We need a report that shows what systems have been in a pending status for 0-30 days, 31-60 days, 61-90 days, and 91+ days.  I am soooo close to getting this but I’m at a dead end.  For the examples below I will just use NFC and eOPF as the systems (there are five systems in all).

So the report would read like this:

Pending Date...0-30...31-60...61-90...90+
NFC....................1.........4..........8........1
eOPF..................2.........5..........1........0

I have the table setup with a status field for each group (i.e. NFC Status = “Pending” or “Complete”)

I have another field that has a date submitted (i.e. NFC Submitted Date = “XX/XX/XXXX”)

This is what I have done.  I am only sharing this to give an idea of the direction I was heading.  If there is a better way please let me know.

I created two quires (NFC Requests & eOPF Requests)

The first row field in the query is the status (i.e. NFC Status) with Criteria =”Pending”

The second row is the 0-30 days with the field of NFC 0 - 30 Days: Sum((IIf([Systems Access - Table]![NFC Form Date Submitted]>Date()-31,1,0)))

The third row is NFC 31 - 60 Days: Sum((IIf([Systems Access - Table]![NFC Form Date Submitted]Date()-61,1,0)))

Etc, etc.

So I have two quires that give me that data I need and they work.  Now, I need to figure out a way to combine the quires by changing the fields that calculate NFC and eOPF separately and calculate them together.

I tried to build a summary request report but it wants to push the totals for eOPF over and I can’t line them up.

It looks like this:

Pending Date...0-30...31-60...61-90...90+...0-30...31-60...61-90...90+
NFC....................1.........4...........8........1
eOPF..............................................................2.........5.........1.........0

I’m getting frustrated and could really use some help.

- Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a "crosstab" query google a nit and you'll find many good examples for ms access.

This is one that helped me alot.

http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=25